# Python suddenly stopped importing pip-installed modules/packages

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I was working on a flask project, which had been working until today. Suddenly, Python has an ModuleNotFoundError for all modules installed using pip.

I'm using Python 3.7 on Windows 10, and have an virtualenv for the project. I know the modules are installed because they show up when I type "pip list". The site-packages for the installed modules all contain an init file too, which was one solution to the error I saw. I have no idea what I suddenly did to cause this.

Comment: What OS are you on?  Did anything change when you activated the virtualenv from before today?  Did you install anything new today?  When you type python in the command line or terminal after activating the virtualenv, do you get the version you are expecting to?  What are you doing to get the modules not found  error message?

Comment: Psychic debugging: Did you just install 3.7? There is a decent chance you're using a `pip` installed with 3.6 (or earlier) and it's (correctly) listing all the installed packages for that version of Python, while 3.7 has nothing installed (having not existed until recently).

Comment: try to run the python shell and import a package. What happen?